# replace the inside of a href with the inside of img tag

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have some divs in an html file. Now in each div a href should be the same as img src.
That means if img src looks like this: `<img src="media/gallery/Mr. G.jpeg">`
then the a href, in which the img is, should look automaticly like this:
`<a href="media/gallery/Mr. G.jpeg">`

In the screenshot you can see my code, can anyone help me?
[my div](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4rzEM.png)

I have tried unsuccessfully to write code with javascript. I am currently still learning and am unfortunately not so good at JS yet.

Comment: Relevant code and error messages need to be included in your question *as text*, [not as pictures of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/328193).  Just linking to screen shots makes it more difficult for people to help you.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: Having said that... It's not entirely clear to me what you're asking.  You claim the `<a>` should direct the user to the same URL in the `<img>`, and the [picture of] code shown appears to do just that.  What isn't working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get all the container elements with `document.querySelectorAll`, then loop over them to set each `href` to match the image.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.content_section_item').forEach(el => {
    const a = el.querySelector('a');
    a.href = a.querySelector('img').src;
});
```